# 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update' when inserting a row into a table

Tags: ios, swift

I've been getting this error when I try to insert a row in my table. I've looked at the other answers for hours but either they are doing something different or it is written in Objective C. I'm very new to swift so I may be doing something obviously wrong that i just cant figure out.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SwiftDate

class LaunchesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var launchesTable: UITableView!

    var launches : [Launch]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        loadLaunches()
    }

    func loadLaunches()
    {

        Alamofire.request("http://10.0.0.26:5000/V1/Launches/Test", method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in

            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)

            let jsonArray = json.arrayValue

            self.launches = []

            for jsonObject in jsonArray {

                self.launches.append(Launch(launchDate:     jsonObject["LaunchDate"].string?.toDate(),  launchName: jsonObject["LaunchName"].string))
            }

            self.onLaunchesLoaded()
        }
    }

    func onLaunchesLoaded()
    {
        self.launchesTable.beginUpdates()
        self.launchesTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .none)
        self.launchesTable.endUpdates()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your `numberOfRows` function from your table view data source class.  If you are reloading the whole array, you should just call `reloadData` instead of inserting a single row. Also you will need to update the table on the main queue, since your network request will complete on a background thread.

Comment: data source class? I dont have one. Im assuming thats the problem?

Comment: Yes.  Have you looked at a table view tutorial online?  There are many.  You need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` functions to let the tableview know how many rows it contains and to supply a cell for each row.

Comment: `self.launches` is your data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your table view's data source properly. 
First, specify the number of sections via `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and number of rows `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` based on the data that is returned by your network request. Also, because table view cells are reused the best way to populate the table view cells is through the table view data source `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method instead of calling `insertRows()` method. This should be covered in the [Basics of TableView Creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html).

Comment: The 2nd half here doesn't make sense. You have to use `cellForRowAt` no matter what. `insertRows` is optional and depends on how you add rows to the table view.